# Will try-with-resources close resources if exception happens?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Will try-with-resources close all opened resources if exception happens?

```
private void insertUserInAccessTable(int user_id) throws SQLException {
    final String sql = "bla bla";   
    try( Connection con = ...; PreparedStatement ps = ... ) {
        ...
        if(i==0) throw new SQLException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the whole point of try-with-resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not ones that were initialized outside of the try block or inside its body (after the resource declarations).

```
// This connection is initialized beforehand and will not be
// closed automatically by try-with-resources
Connection conn = // ...

// The statement WILL always be closed, exception or not, before exiting the try block
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement())
{
    // This result set will NOT be closed (directly) by try-with-resources
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(/*...*/);
}
```

<sup>*</sup> When try-with-resources closes the `Statement`, JDBC says the statement should close the `ResultSet` it created.  So it may get closed, but only because of the JDBC contract and not because of try-with-resources.

Comment: Oracles tutorial shows ResultSet come in life inside try block body and it will be closed too because statement will be, will not?

Comment: @Andy That's a JDBC feature, and works only if your JDBC driver is implemented correctly to spec.  It doesn't hold for all closeable objects in general.  The only things try-with-resources will close are those items listed in the resource declaration for the try block.

Answer (score 4):

It will be closed even if it will throw an exception.

> it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes
>   normally or abruptly

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html